# This use of PreparedStatement; can be vulnerable to SQL injection (with JDBC)

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle, prepared-statement

My sql query looks like this:

```
String sqlAlloc = " select %1$s from %2$s "
  + "where plot_fk in (%3$s) and plot_fk between ? and ? "
  + "and f001=? "
  + "and repdate=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(?,'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-Mon-YY') "
  + "and reportname = ? and change_status in (0,2,6,8,9)";
if (!cond.isEmpty()) {
                sqlAlloc += " and C007=?";
            }
if (tableName.getKey().equals(ALLOC_PENSIONFUNDS)) {
  sqlAlloc += " group by REPDATE, F001, C007, REPORTNAME, COLNAME, ROWNAME";
            }
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(tableName.getValue().split(","));
String sqlAllocFormatted = String.format(sqlAlloc,
  values.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")),
  jdbcUsernameMaster + "." + key,
  plotFkMasterPublicList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
try (final Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
     final PreparedStatement stmtAlloc =
       conn.prepareStatement(sqlAllocFormatted);) {
  ...
```

When I scan my code with sonarqube I get the following msg:
This use of PreparedStatement; can be vulnerable to SQL injection (with JDBC)

I don't really understand what is wrong with the sql query and how to fix this?

Comment: @TheImpaler The vulnerability is in the values of `values` and `jdbcUsernameMaster`, `key` and `plotFkMasterPublicList`, which are interpolated in the query string using `String.format`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You are right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vulnerability lies in the fact that you are using `String.format` to inject things into your query string. If the values of `values`/`tableName` and `jdbcUsernameMaster`, `key` and `plotFkMasterPublicList` come from an untrusted source, then this could be a potential source of SQL injection.

To fix this, you either need to not use `String.format`, but static query strings, or you need to ensure that your values are not from an untrusted source (e.g. user input, external services, etc), and then consciously suppress the warning as a false-positive.

Comment: tableName is configured by client. How to handle this?

Comment: @Ronald Use an allowlist of possible values, or check the values against database metadata, use a denylist of characters, ensure proper quoting of values, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Injection is really hard to exploit in this particulare case, but if you know the query executed and plotFKMAsterPublicList can be manipultated you can create a "bad query".
What follows is an example based on your original code:

```
        String sqlAlloc = " select %1$s from %2$s "
            + "where plot_fk in (%3$s) and plot_fk between ? and ? "
            + "and f001=? "
            + "and repdate=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(?,'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-Mon-YY') "
            + "and reportname = ? and change_status in (0,2,6,8,9)";
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("col1,col2".split(","));
    List plotFkMasterPublicList= new ArrayList<>();
    plotFkMasterPublicList.add("plot1");
    plotFkMasterPublicList.add("plot2");
    plotFkMasterPublicList.add("plot3) union all select col1,col2 from user.table union all select  col1,col2 from user.table where (1=1 ");
    String sqlAllocFormatted = String.format(sqlAlloc,
            values.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")),
            "user" + "." + "table",
            plotFkMasterPublicList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));

    System.out.println(sqlAllocFormatted);
```

Thanks to @MarkRotteveel suggestion you can query whatever you want, see these example:

```
        String sqlAlloc = " select %1$s from %2$s "
            + "where plot_fk in (%3$s) and plot_fk between ? and ? "
            + "and f001=? "
            + "and repdate=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(?,'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-Mon-YY') "
            + "and reportname = ? and change_status in (0,2,6,8,9)";
    List<String> values = Arrays.asList("* from any_table -- col1,col2".split(","));
    List plotFkMasterPublicList= new ArrayList<>();
    plotFkMasterPublicList.add("plot1");
    plotFkMasterPublicList.add("plot2");
    String sqlAllocFormatted = String.format(sqlAlloc,
            values.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")),
            "user" + "." + "table",
            plotFkMasterPublicList.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(",")));

    System.out.println(sqlAllocFormatted);
```

Comment: It is simpler to exploit than you think. If you can control the first value(s), then you only need to include a `--` to be able to ignore the rest of the query then you have a free for all with the first part.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you are right, I'm not a "good exploiter"